# Unable to run an extension's "functional test" within a TYPO3 CMS 7.6.11 project

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

After running `composer install` and installing TYPO3 CMS 7.6.11 via it's Install Tool I created an TYPO3 Extension with one test which extends TYPO3's `FunctionalTestCase`. When i run this test I get this error message:

```
PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: Fatal error: Class 'TYPO3\CMS\Core\Tests\FunctionalTestCaseBootstrapUtility' not found in /Volumes/Projects/MyProject/Web/vendor/typo3/cms/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Tests/FunctionalTestCase.php on line 203
```

I searched for `TYPO3\CMS\Core\Tests\FunctionalTestCaseBootstrapUtility` in the project but could indeed not find this class.

This is my test case:

```
<?php
namespace Acme\MyProject\Tests\Functional;

use TYPO3\CMS\Core\Tests\FunctionalTestCase;

class FooTest extends FunctionalTestCase
{
    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function foo()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

Note: after running `composer install` no `Tests` directories exist in any of TYPO3's system extensions – AFAIK this behaviour was introduced with TYPO3 CMS 7.6.10.

Am I missing something? Is there a solution for my problem?

Comment: Related: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/77964

Comment: Have you checked my latest comment at forge?

Comment: @GeorgRinger Yes, thank you. I unfortunately found the forge ticket only after I wrote this question here at stackoverflow. At the moment we automatically deploy (exactly) the tested TYPO3 CMS instance – I guess using `preferred-install` and `source` for `typo3/cms` will work for us – as long as we exclude the `.git` directory from deployment. Unfortunately using `source` will slow down our builds because composer will (a) not be able to load `typo3/cms` from composer's cache and (b) will (by definition) not use a distribution (which "can speed up installs substantially"), right?

Comment: right, the core team is currently planning how to improve the situation as the .gitattributes file has also some advantages like improved handling on WIN and smaller downloads

Comment: Thanks for the information that there are plans to improve the situation! :)

Comment: Hey, can either of you add the solution from forge as answer to this question? Self-answering is accepted behavior on stackoverflow. This way the answer would not be hidden in the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use --prefer-source in composer or at least tell composer to do a source installation of the typo3/cms package:

```
"config": {
    "preferred-install": {
        "typo3/cms": "source",
        "*": "dist" 
    },
}
```

Credits to @georg-ringer

https://forge.typo3.org/issues/77964#note-3

Comment: This works but makes our builds *really* slow. Any other suggestions? Does anybody know how the TYPO3 core team is planning to handle this problem to execute functional tests?